# Need to display "any" JSON in a animated TreeView

Tags: angular

I've been looking for a way to display any JSON in a treeview that can be collapsed & expanded.

I've looked over a few (angular-tree-component, angular-json-tree, react-treeview) but it looks like most of them require JSON that follows a particular structure (ie., has an ID/Name element etc..)

I like https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-json-view  But I'm struggling a bit with using React alongside Angular (I'm really new to Angular)

Any help or suggestions?

Edit: Angular5

Answer (score 0):

Most of what I found was pre-angular5  I'm sure I could have used them after jumping through some hoops.  But I finally found ngx-json-viewer and it worked for this issue. Though I'd love to hear other solutions.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-json-viewer